# replica set in MongoDB using docker, primary has error and stops being primary when another member is added to the set

Tags: mongodb

I have two docker containers running a mongo instance each, they were initialized like this:

```
docker run --name mongodb-shard-1-node-1 -d -v mongodb-shard-1-node-1:/data/db -p 27031:27017 mongo --replSet rs0 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128
```

when i do `docker inspect mongodb-shard-1-node-1` it shows the ip 172.17.0.2

```
docker run --name mongodb-shard-1-node-2 -d -v mongodb-shard-1-node-2:/data/db -p 27020:27017 mongo --replSet rs0 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128
```

when i do `docker inspect mongodb-shard-1-node-2` it shows the ip 172.17.0.4

So i proceed to access `mongodb-shard-1-node-1` by using `docker exec -it mongodb-shard-1-node-1 mongo` and i initialize it as the primary member like this:

```
rs.initiate()
{
    "info2" : "no configuration specified. Using a default configuration for the set",
    "me" : "ee3c41ef76b2:27017",
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Then I proceed to add the `mongodb-shard-1-node-2` to this member for it to work as a secondary member, at first it looks like it worked:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.add("172.17.0.4:27017")
{ "ok" : 1 }
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "rs0",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-05-20T01:04:02.095Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "term" : NumberLong(1),
    "members" : [ervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
            {       "_id" : 0,
                    "name" : "ee3c41ef76b2:27017",
                    "state" : 1,,
                    "uptime" : 27,PRIMARY",
                    "optime""ts" : Timestamp(1463706237, 1),
                    },      "t" : NumberLong(1)
                    "infoMessage" : "could not find member to sync from",
                    "electionDate" : ISODate("2016-05-20T01:03:43Z"),
                    "self" : truen" : 2,
            {,
                    "name" : "172.17.0.4:27017",
                    "state" : 0,,
                    "uptime" : 4,"STARTUP",
                    "optime""ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                    },      "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                    "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2016-05-20T01:04:01.187Z"),
                    "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),Date("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            }       "configVersion" : -2
    "ok" : 1
}
```

but right away it fails for some reason and i have no idea why, here's what i get:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.status()
2016-05-20T01:04:18.007+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: error doing query:
failed: network error while attempting to run command 'replSetGetStatus' on host '127.0.0.1:27017'  :
DB.prototype.runCommand@src/mongo/shell/db.js:135:1
DB.prototype.adminCommand@src/mongo/shell/db.js:153:16
rs.status@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:1090:12
@(shell):1:1

2016-05-20T01:04:18.012+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1) failed
2016-05-20T01:04:18.018+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] reconnect 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1) ok
rs0:SECONDARY
```

What is wrong? How do I fix it?

**Edit**: just to clarify, i had already tried the connections between the containers by doing what [this part](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/troubleshoot-replica-sets/) of the documentation says at: Test Connections Between all Members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary is trying to auto-configure itself as `ee3c41ef76b2:27017` and that then resolves to the loopback (`127.0.0.1`) which is then not responding on the container as it expects.  Depending on what the second container does to resolve `ee3c41ef76b2`, and especially it it does not resolve to `172.17.0.2`, it will probably not be able to talk to the primary either.

Assuming you are correct about the connectivity (and you have verified that the instances are listening on the IP and not just the loopback) then you need to override the automatic detection and be explicit when you are calling `rs.initiate()`, something like this:

```
rs.initiate(
   {
      _id: "rs0",
      version: 1,
      members: [
         { _id: 0, host : "172.17.0.2:27017" },
         { _id: 1, host : "172.17.0.4:27017" }
      ]
   }
)
```

Comment: This worked like a charm thank you, and after the initiate I was able to add an arbiter without issue. Something that i forgot to mention (and I am NOT sure if it's related to the issue but it may be) is that I'm getting a warning that says `[initandlisten] ** WARNING: Insecure configuration, access control is not enabled and no --bind_ip has been specified.` and then `the server listens on all available network interfaces.`, the default --bind_ip setting is (`127.0.0.1`) as seen here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/ but I couldn't figure out what to do of it.

Comment: you can add a bind_ip option to listen on the 172.17.0.X addresses to the respective config files, you can then decide whether to bind the loopback too if you so wish.  Without the option specified, MongoDB will listen on all interfaces it finds - this can lead to security issues where the database ends up listening on an unintended interface (one with a public IP for example), hence the warning.  Less of a concern with containers, but still best practice to be explicit